# Cant SSH to my Google Cloud VM instance anymore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh

Hoping someone can help me with this. The title says it all, I cant SSH to my VM instance.

What I am seeing:

1 . If I try to SSH normally, the process just loops endlessly (I actually think the first time I got a msg at the very end, but now I stop after maybe 20-40 secs) - the msgs that loop include (not necessarily in this order):

- "Transferring SSH Keys to VM"
- "The key transfer to project metadata is taking an unusually long time. Transferring instead to
  instance of meta data maybe be faster, but will transfer the keys to only this    VM...[msg continued]"
- "Establishing connection to SSH server..."
  "Could not connect, retying (!/3).. THe VM Series console output may
  provide details..."

2 .  There seems to be a large number of SSH KEYs that are being generated as a side effect of this process, common to all - they are relatively short (just 1,5 lines) and end with "expireOn

3 . Tried creating a key with puttyGen and then logging in with Putty but the result is: "Server refused our key" + a "Putty Fata Error" pop up with : Disconnected: No sypported authetification methods available (Server sent: publickey)

4 . Tried the serial console way ([Google Compute Engine - can't ssh to it after debian upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52124642/google-compute-engine-cant-ssh-to-it-after-debian-upgrade) and its being referred in many places but ) - but that only gets me to the serial console which remains unresponsive to my charms.(So thats like step 9 and no login credentials ever get asked.

5 . Also went through the rabbit hole a few times and tried every thing else I could find, lost track

6 . FTP still working just fine

7 . I have added manually SSH keys, tried logging in via the different console options etc etc but just not getting anywhere

8 . Not a memory issue, all though I see CPU% spiking close to 90% when I try some of the login methods..

9 .  My site is just in the build stage at this point- so that might be the reason - but seeing a recommendation in the console that haven't seen before across my other projects: "Shut down VM to save $4.31/month" first time ever Google recommends you to spend less.

10 . I am running a bitnami WP instance.

11 .  Of and at the very start I received this message too: Permission denied (publickey), but cant reproduce it anymore since too confused by a mile (kilometer actually)

12 . (Edit) almost forgot - also before all this happened, even before this particular VM was created I believe, came across a tutorial/comment mentioning getting locked out etc and started the installation of the local environment, so able to actually start a connection via **Command prompt** BUT after "**gcloud compute ssh user@instance**" I get:

- updating project ssh meta data.. working, updated
- updating project meta data..done
- Waiting for SSH key to propagate
- SFATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
- SFATAL ERROR: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
- ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not SSH into the instance.  It is possible that your SSH key has not propagated to the instance yet. Try running this command again.  If you still cannot connect, verify that the firewall and instance are set to accept ssh traffic.

12 . **Why is this happening (potentially)**?
Hard to say BUT... Noted the following msg by Google Cloud during an attempt to work on this(https://onepagezen.com/automatic-backups-google-cloud/ just as I was transitioning to step 2 where SSH needs to be started) - anyway the Message was:
"Google recommends updating from Global DNS to Zonal DNS to reduce the risk from future cross-regional outages. If you experience connection issues you can revert this update by removing this key-value pair from the meta data page"
-> I suspect that my click on that messages "UPDATE" button is what has taxed 12-18 hrs of my life so far.

I feel like #3 (putty) could be further explored, read somewhere about the key formats needing  formatting or something similar as I was going through about a million and 1 websites

Also maybe there is someway to execute #4 better - but not sure as I found the same instructions from about 3 places, tried them to the letter, always getting the same result (the definition of madness creeping in) + at least 2 of the places where I found the instructions referenced were mentioning that even the original poster failed to get past the same point I am stuck at.
(so at this point: I am following instructions where the instruction include a note warning you that this doesnt work..coo coo)

Also, not sure exactly what the next step would be, whats the command to run to tell my VM/SSH to start playing nice again.

Both of those options smell like hacks to me as the VM should just work with SSH console, period - kind of frustrating that you cant just do a hard reset of (SSH) access - ideal would be to "activate a master key" and just reset the SSH access rule or what ever.

I have set up SSL running on my WP instance , pointed the domain nameservers, so may end up just killing this , FTP'ing my theme to safety and restarting a new instance completely - thats just kind of stupid but computer keeps saying no.

Can anyone help?
Thanks
Sami

---

UPDATED:
SO I Took johns advice - as well as I knew how.(**long story short, my life improved see below if relevant to your particular case**)

1. Started serial port - started up fine - but is not responsive to anything I say or do. SO cant get it to respond, I remeber reading a post somewhere that unless you do something it is basically a 1 way log of activity or something of that sort. I think that must be the case for me. (I tried the instructions on the post I am referring to previously, not 100% sure if execution was correct but I wasnt able to achieve anything. I also Immediatelly tried to follow steps to "roll back" any changes, cant remeber details or wether I managed to do it, just satýing serial oport remains unresponsive)

Serial loads up and says:

serialport: Connected to PROJECT.europe-ZONE1-c.INSTANCENAME-v
m port 1 (session ID: b01300da7224ac676878aa8cf5adb784f6f24f4b, active connectio
ns: 1).
May  8 06:51:54 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewa
l in 1448 seconds.
May  8 07:16:02 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.132.0.2 on
ens4 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
May  8 07:16:02 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: DHCPACK of 10.132.0.2 from 16
9.254.169.254
May  8 07:16:02 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewa
l in 1709 seconds.
May  8 07:44:31 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.132.0.2 on
ens4 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
May  8 07:44:31 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: DHCPACK of 10.132.0.2 from 16
9.254.169.254
May  8 07:44:31 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewa
l in 1519 seconds.
May  8 08:09:50 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.132.0.2 on
ens4 to 169.254.169.254 port 67
May  8 08:09:50 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: DHCPACK of 10.132.0.2 from 16
9.254.169.254
May  8 08:09:50 INSTANCENAME dhclient[453]: bound to 10.132.0.2 -- renewa
l in 1526 seconds.

So nothing there, didnt know how to proceed. with some googling found the instructions on how to start my instance via CMD prompt on my local win machine - and happened to find just the right instructions so that I managed to get it done.
**(CMD PROMPT: gcloud compute ssh INSTANCENAME incase anyone is equally novce and stuck but lucky enough to have the right settings for that to work)**

Anyway so glad to see the Bitnami screen, I cant tell you.

Anyway then I ran:
**CMD PROMPT: df -h**

And the output was:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            284M     0  284M   0% /dev
tmpfs            59M  252K   59M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        32G  5.0G   25G  17% /
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           118M     0  118M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda15      124M  7.9M  116M   7% /boot/efi

So as far as I can tell disk space isnt an issue.But I wasnt really able to complete the steps John instructed, at least I dont think so.

**And while I am "back in" I am not sure what to do next, what steps to take to:**
Normalize my situation -> I would just feel safer if the GCC SSH window would work, also the set up behind my local key and the CMD Prompt access is currently a bit of a mystery to me, since in the process of this mess I have seen about 200 new keys being generated automatically or by me on purpose and I have also deleted so many - so I while I consider this access, I also consider it extremely fragile with probablity of future mess up ( I do see this as an opportunity to learn as well which is nice, I have a goal and now that theres been a bit of progress again its not such a depressing experience)

Diagnose properly  -> to get my feet on the ground and orient myself to my status - when you start a fresh instance you know whats happening and now it all looks sort of ok" but I feel like I have a big messy yeard and a mailbox full of unpaid bills - its just looking for an excuse to crash down.

Make a back up / Image (what ever its called) - > this is something I wil bee googling next, as long as I am safely on the edge, I might as well create a back up (every now and then) to pull back on to the ledge when eventuality happens. I have seen instructions around this already, but if anyone can tell me what to do really - I would appreciate, creating a back up and restoring from one.

Also - if anyone can help, please share whats the topic to study into to take off this blindfold I feel I am wearing - I mean I wanted to set up I AM & ORGANIZATIOn to manage better some resources the company I work for has and I couldnt find what to study, yes there were courses on becoming a GC administrator and hints of how an organization could be created but it was a heavy load when all I wanted to do was find instructions on: How to set up organization, distribute resources and access right, even on a simple conceptual level (picture), instead the instructions look like they are for grown ups :-(

ok - so hoping for a reply, at the moment sharing incase anyone else googles and lands and finds relief. The despair is the worst.

(and this might come in handy: https://onepagezen.com/manage-wordpress-files-on-google-cloud-platform/)

---

**UPDATE**
OK it was too good to be true
1 - CMD access no longer works the same
2 - site is returning http 500
3 - Serial connection actually did give some outpu which might be waht John was asking me to look for and it does have plenty of stuff, but I am fairly certain I wont be able to decipher on my on:

```
serialport: Connected to PROJECTNAME.europe-ZONE1-c.InstanceNAME port 1 (session ID: a6fbbea04cbc09e185d475b10fafbe6b8e67f627, active connections: 1

## 2021-05-08 09:41:50+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/070_change_boot_log_permissions...

## 2021-05-08 09:41:50+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/080_prevent_incoming_connections...

## 2021-05-08 09:41:52+00:00 ## INFO ## 80 has been blocked
## 2021-05-08 09:41:54+00:00 ## INFO ## 443 has been blocked
## 2021-05-08 09:41:54+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/090_get_default_passwords...
## 2021-05-08 09:41:54+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/100_regenerate_keys...
## 2021-05-08 09:41:54+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/110_configure_default_passwords...
## 2021-05-08 09:41:54+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/120_reenable_incoming_connections...
## 2021-05-08 09:41:54+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/130_gce_initialize_monitoring...
## 2021-05-08 09:41:54+00:00 ## INFO ## Starting services...

ssh/opt/bitnami/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql could not be started
/opt/bitnami/php/scripts/ctl.sh : php-fpm started
Syntax OK
/opt/bitnami/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started at port 80
## 2021-05-08 09:44:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/010_bitnami_agent_extra...
## 2021-05-08 09:44:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/020_bitnami_agent...
## 2021-05-08 09:44:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/030_update_ip...
## 2021-05-08 09:44:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Automatic IP update disabled
## 2021-05-08 09:44:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/040_update_welcome_file...
## 2021-05-08 09:44:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/050_bitnami_credentials_file...
## 2021-05-08 09:44:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/060_start_gonit...
Starting gonit daemon

## 2021-05-08 09:44:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/070_clean_metadata...[....] Starting enhanced syslogd: rsyslogdMay 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] Linux version 4.19.0-16-cloud-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19)

May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-16-cloud-amd64 root=UUID=2a1f125c-0d4f-4ae8-9235-57ddc9e55fc2 ro console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk=ttyS0,115200 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=Y
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'

May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]: 576, xstate_sizes[2]: 256
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'standard' format.

May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009fbff] usable
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009fc00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000265fcfff] usable
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000265fd000-0x00000000265fffff] reserved
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fffbc000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] bootconsole [earlyser0] enabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] SMBIOS 2.4 present.
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] DMI: Google Google Compute Engine/Google Compute Engine, BIOS Google 01/01/2011
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] Hypervisor detected: KVM
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000000] kvm-clock: Using msrs 4b564d01 and 4b564d00
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000001] kvm-clock: cpu 0, msr 17747001, primary cpu clock
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000001] kvm-clock: using sched offset of 4896912345 cycles
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.000836] clocksource: kvm-clock: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x1cd42e4dffb, max_idle_ns: 881590591483 ns
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.004060] tsc: Detected 2299.998 MHz processor
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.005407] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.005409] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.005413] last_pfn = 0x265fd max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006193] MTRR default type: write-back
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006194] MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006196] 00000-9FFFF write-back
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006196] A0000-BFFFF uncachable
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006197] C0000-FFFFF write-protect
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006198] MTRR variable ranges enabled:
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006199] 0 base 000080000000 mask 3FFF80000000 uncachable
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006200] 1 disabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006200] 2 disabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006200] 3 disabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006201] 4 disabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006201] 5 disabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006202] 6 disabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006202] 7 disabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.006218] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB WC UC- UC WB WP UC- WT 
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.008441] Using GB pages for direct mapping
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.009291] RAMDISK: [mem 0x251d3000-0x25f35fff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.010064] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.010948] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000F24C0 000014 (v00 Google)
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.011781] ACPI: RSDT 0x00000000265FFFA0 000038 (v01 Google GOOGRSDT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.013308] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000265FF3C0 0000F4 (v02 Google GOOGFACP 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.014609] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000265FDB00 0018BA (v01 Google GOOGDSDT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)

May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.015851] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000265FDAC0 000040
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.016507] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000265FDAC0 000040
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.017113] ACPI: SRAT 0x00000000265FFE80 0000B8 (v03 Google GOOGSRAT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.018448] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000265FFDE0 00006E (v05 Google GOOGAPIC 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.019726] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000265FF4C0 00091F (v01 Google GOOGSSDT 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.021650] ACPI: WAET 0x00000000265FFE50 000028 (v01 Google GOOGWAET 00000001 GOOG 00000001)
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.023503] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.023609] SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0x00 -> Node 0
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.024385] ACPI: SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0 [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.025647] ACPI: SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0 [mem 0x00100000-0x265fffff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.026852] NUMA: Node 0 [mem 0x00000000-0x0009ffff] + [mem 0x00100000-0x265fcfff] -> [mem 0x00000000-0x265fcfff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.028376] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x265f8000-0x265fcfff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.029182] Zone ranges:
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.029537] DMA [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.030432] DMA32 [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000265fcfff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.031277] Normal empty
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.031782] Device empty
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.032176] Movable zone start for each node
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.032838] Early memory node ranges
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.033324] node 0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009efff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.034197] node 0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000265fcfff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.035203] Zeroed struct page in unavailable ranges: 6757 pages
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.035204] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x00000000265fcfff]
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.037254] On node 0 totalpages: 157083
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.037261] DMA zone: 64 pages used for memmap
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.037261] DMA zone: 21 pages reserved
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.037262] DMA zone: 3998 pages, LIFO batch:0
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.037357] DMA32 zone: 2392 pages used for memmap
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.037358] DMA32 zone: 153085 pages, LIFO batch:31
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.041184] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0xb008
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.041873] ACPI: Local APIC address 0xfee00000
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 0.041887] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] dfl dfl lint[0x1])

May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: <1054>[ 3.843741] systemd-udevd[375]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 3.848202] sd 0:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 4.367124] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: discard,errors=remount-ro
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 4.763454] FAT-fs (sda15): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 4.978198] audit: type=1400 audit(1620466905.868:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/chronyd" pid=1063 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 4.983558] audit: type=1400 audit(1620466905.872:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/haveged" pid=1064 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 4.993751] audit: type=1400 audit(1620466905.884:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=1065 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 4.996523] audit: type=1400 audit(1620466905.884:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=1065 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 4.999527] audit: type=1400 audit(1620466905.884:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_groff" pid=1065 comm="apparmor[....] Starting Apache httpd web server: apache2_parser"
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 5.010417] audit: type=1400 audit(1620466905.900:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1066 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 5.013743] audit: type=1400 audit(1620466905.900:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1066 comm="apparmor_parser"
May 8 09:44:06 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 8.625539] Adding 649996k swap on /mnt/.bitnami.swap. Priority:-2 extents:14 across:4549388k FSAH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80no listening sockets available, shutting downAH00015: Unable to open logsAction 'start' failed.The Apache error log may have more information.. 
ok 
[ ok ] Starting deferred execution scheduler: atd.
[....] Starting time daemon: chronyd
May 8 09:44:10 InstanceNAME chronyd[2562]: chronyd version 3.4 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC +PRIVDROP +SCFILTER +SIGND +ASYNCDNS +SECHASH +IPV6 -DEBUG)
May 8 09:44:10 InstanceNAME chronyd[2562]: Frequency -85.906 +/- 0.002 ppm read from /var/lib/chrony/chrony.drift
May 8 09:44:10 InstanceNAME chronyd[2562]: Loaded seccomp filter.
 ok 
[ ok ] Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
[ ok ] Starting system message bus: dbus.
[ ok ] Starting MTA: exim4.
May 8 09:44:11 [ 150.538649] audit: type=1400 audit(1620467051.428:9): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/haveged" name="/run/haveged.pid" pid=2952 comm="haveged" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
InstanceNAME haveged: haveged starting up
May 8 09:44:11 InstanceNAME kernel: [ 150.538649] audit: type=1400 audit(1620467051.428:9): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/haveged" name="/run/haveged.pid" pid=2952 comm="haveged" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[ ok ] Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd
.[warn] Starting Stackdriver metrics collection agent: stackdriver-agent[....] disabled via metadata ... (warning). 
(warning).
[FAIL] startpar: service(s) returned failure: bitnami ... failed!
May 8 09:44:14 InstanceNAME chronyd[2562]: Selected source 169.254.169.254
```

Can anyone make any sense of this?

Comment: Enable the Compute Engine serial port and review the console output: a) from system boot to see if there is a problem such as no disk space b) while connecting with ssh to see server-side issues. This question has been asked and answered many times on Stackoverflow. Some of the answers are very good.

Comment: Thanks John. I will follow the steps you described - I have visited many of these  questions across many sites , related to this issue and havent been able to solve it using those instructions (could be due to my own limited knowledge) - but also have a feeling that in a significant amount of the threads I have come across, maybe 10% or even as high as 25% it looked like the poster never ended up resolving (or stopped updating), but several do end in a fashion where this is explicitly stated (that its not solved/no answer found) - but like I said, I will try those steps described - thanks!

Comment: Look at the VM configuration in the Google Cloud Console. What do you have configured for `Cloud API access scopes`? Look at the assigned Service Account. What IAM roles are assigned to the service account?

Comment: You have multiple problems with this instance. I think the root of your problems is that the file system is corrupted, and you need to run the Linux command `fsck`. This document will help you set up the serial port so that you can run `fsck` manually. Make sure you understand this command first. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console#connectserialconsole

Comment: Hi - thanks guys for the replies. I managed to by pass my problem, forget it for a second and while doing something else noticed these replies, looks like there is so much info I may have begun to understand this more and so may even be able to fix the issue - thank you!